# Calculating number of spanning trees of complete graph with each edge divided

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

When calculating the number of spanning trees of complete graph $K_n$ with adding an extra vertex to every edge, I've noticed that the number of spanning trees is always equal to:

$$n^{n - 2}*2^{n - 1\choose 2}$$

I understand that $n^{n - 2}$ comes from Cayley's formula, but why $2^{n - 1\choose 2}$?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "adding an extra vertex to every edge", do you mean that there is a new vertex placed in the middle of every edge, thus creating two new edges for every edge in the original $K_n$?

Comment: @JosephHarrison yes, let's have K3 - a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a, after adding each vertex to each edge we have graph: a <-> d, d <-> b, b <-> e, e <-> c, c <-> f, f <-> a.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: In a spanning tree of $K_n$ there are $\binom{n-1}{2}$ edges that will not be used. Each of these edges now contains a vertices and each will have exactly $2$ ways to add an edge to complete the spanning tree.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit nice, thanks!